# Error in my SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL and trying to create a stored procedure to learn how parameters and variables work. When I create below stored procedure, I assigned 2 parameters and 2 variables. I set the value for the variables.

The stored procedure is created but when I go to run it as

```
EXECUTE anniversary_file @year = 2017, @month = 3
```

I get this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure anniversary_file, Line 53
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE anniversary_file
    @year DATETIME,
    @month DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @month1 AS DATETIME,
            @year1 AS DATETIME

    SET @month1 = (SELECT MONTH(C.OrderCompletionDate) FROM dbo.Customers AS   C)
    SET @year1 = (SELECT  YEAR(C.OrderCompletionDate) FROM dbo.Customers AS C)

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CustomerID,
        BAN_ADSL_TN,
        LandlinePhoneNumber,
        MobilePhoneNumber,
        FirstName, LastName,
        ServiceAddress,
        ServiceAddressAptNo,
        ServiceAddressCity,
        ServiceAddressState,
        ServiceAddressZip,
        --MailingAddress,
        --MailingAddressAptNo,
        --MailingAddressCity,
        --MailingAddressState,
        --MailingAddressZip,
        --LanguageID,
        --OrderStatus,
        OrderCompletionDate 
    FROM 
        dbo.Customers AS C (NOLOCK)
    WHERE 
        StatusID = 115
        AND @year = @year1
        AND @month = @month1
END
```

Comment: You don't even need to set those variables, `@month1` and `@year1`.  In the `Where` clause compare your input variables to the `MONTH(C.OrderCompletionDate)` and `YEAR(C.OrderCompletionDate)` functions.

Comment: The error is very clear, your subquery returns more than 1 value.  Fix your subquery.

Comment: Be careful with NOLOCK hint. It is far more sinister than most people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ And if you are going to use it you MUST use the WITH keyword. Omitting it has been deprecated since sql server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, these lines are your problem:

```
SET @month1 = (SELECT MONTH(C.OrderCompletionDate) FROM dbo.Customers AS C)
SET @year1 = (SELECT  YEAR(C.OrderCompletionDate) FROM dbo.Customers AS C)
```

If you run those statements separatly, you'll notice at least one returns more than one value

```
SELECT MONTH(C.OrderCompletionDate) FROM dbo.Customers 
SELECT  YEAR(C.OrderCompletionDate) FROM dbo.Customers
```

Thus, you are trying to insert a result **set** into a variable which expects a single value. This can be corrected a few ways.

Adding `TOP 1` with the appropriate `ORDER BY`

```
SET @month1 = (SELECT TOP 1 MONTH(C.OrderCompletionDate) FROM dbo.Customers AS C ORDER BY C.OrderCompletionDate DESC)
SET @year1 = (SELECT  TOP 1 YEAR(C.OrderCompletionDate) FROM dbo.Customers AS C ORDER BY C.OrderCompletionDate DESC)
```

Add a `WHERE` clause...

```
SET @month1 = (SELECT MONTH(C.OrderCompletionDate) FROM dbo.Customers AS C WHERE <some clause to limit the result set>)
SET @year1 = (SELECT  YEAR(C.OrderCompletionDate) FROM dbo.Customers AS C WHERE <some clause to limit the result set>)
```

Additionally, you have your variables declared as a `DATETIME` but are passing in an `INTEGER`

```
DECLARE @month1 AS DATETIME
DECLARE @year1 AS DATETIME
```

These should be `INT` since `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` return an `INTEGER`.

Lastly, your procedure likely doesn't do what you think it will. You can just simplify your code and use this in your `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE StatusID = 115
AND year(OrderCompletionDate) = year(@year)
AND month(OrderCompletionDate)= month(@month)
```

Also, you have your @year and @month parameters declared as a `DATETIME` when you could just use an `INTEGER` and then not use the casting in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It worked thank you so much. I used the second option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the variables. Try this. Remove your variables you are setting and update the `Where` clause as I have.

Declare your input variables as INT.

**UPDATED**

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE anniversary_file
    @year INT,
    @month INT

    AS
    BEGIN

******REMOVE THESE LINES******

    DECLARE @month1 AS DATETIME,
    @year1 AS DATETIME


    SET @month1 = (SELECT MONTH(C.OrderCompletionDate) FROM dbo.Customers AS C)
    SET @year1 = (SELECT  YEAR(C.OrderCompletionDate) FROM dbo.Customers AS C)
 *************************   
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    CustomerID,
    BAN_ADSL_TN,
    LandlinePhoneNumber,
    MobilePhoneNumber,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    ServiceAddress,
    ServiceAddressAptNo,
    ServiceAddressCity,
    ServiceAddressState,
    ServiceAddressZip,
    --MailingAddress,
    --MailingAddressAptNo,
    --MailingAddressCity,
    --MailingAddressState,
    --MailingAddressZip,
    --LanguageID,
    --OrderStatus,
    OrderCompletionDate 
    FROM dbo.Customers AS C (NOLOCK)
    WHERE StatusID = 115
    AND @year = YEAR(C.OrderCompletionDate)
    AND @month = MONTH(C.OrderCompletionDate)

    END
```

Comment: the parameters are declared as `DATETIME`, though I think they should be an INT.

Comment: No worries at all

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate all the help!